# How to do this kinda drawings?

Tags: drawing

Well, I'm pretty newbie to digital drawing / painting, and I'm looking to get into that...

I would like to learn how to do things like those:

http://hemocentros.hol.es/imgs/

(specially images #1, #4, #6 and #7)

I mean, what kinda softwares will I need? Where to start looking for tutorials? Is it possible to do a drawing by hand and then work on it within the softwares?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't forget that a [drawing tablet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_tablet) is pretty much needed for digital drawing/painting. You can do it with mouse... sure.. but just like you can eat soup with a fork, you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any graphic editor software will do the job, something like Photoshop or Gimp if you are looking for a free software (even if it's not as precise as the first one).

In terms of tutorials just start looking on Google or Youtube for any photo manipulation and digital arts tutorial, there are tons of them. Some good resources are:

- http://abduzeedo.com/search/node?keys=tutorials
- https://tutsplus.com/tutorials
- http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/category/tutorials

Yes, it is possible to create your digital artwork from a drawing, you just need to scan your paper, import it on your computer and recreate in your favourite software.